Build exterior cabin walls using plywood siding
I plan to build an occasional-use off-grid cabin in Northern Ontario, Canada.
One option for siding is to use plywood siding (aka T1-11, Smart Board).
The cabin would roughly resemble this, but with a proper floor/base, windows, and larger roof overhangs:

Question:
How is a typical wall built when using plywood siding? For example, from the outside in:

Paint
Plywood siding
Tyvec
Studs filled with pink fibreglass insulation
Vapor barrier
Interior wall panelling such as drywall, tongue and groove boards, etc.

Other details:

Skill level: novice
Budget: minimal
Unorganized township; building permits not possible
Low moisture location; bedrock; forest
Accessible by pickup truck
Heated occasionally with a wood stove


In Canada, every province or territory either uses the National Building Code, or the Provincial Building Code which is modelled on the National.  In days of old you could build cottages, hunting shacks etc to a lower standard than home.  Today, I believe the building codes do not have any allowances for cottage level/shack level  designs.  Or if you prefer, no seasonal designs.  Northern Ontario is a pretty large area.   Another thing you did not mention was access.  Are, you air dropping supplies in, bring supplies in by canoe, skidding stuff in via snowmobile, or building beside pickup?

You can get a building permit.  it may be a laborious process, but not impossible.  Building without a permit could result in eventual fines, condemning the location, or worse.  That is of course should they ever actually find the place and check.  proceed at own risk.  Don't piss off any one who might tattle on you either.

The law changed last year.  https://ero.ontario.ca/notice/019-6847  You should get a permit.

I assume it will not be heated? Does it need to provide any isolation?

@quarague Heated occasionally with a wood stove. I updated the question.

I'd like to provide you with a more focused reading list.
Especially in a wet-cold climate like Northern Ontario, your water-and-vapor control layer (the Tyvek) and second vapor control layer (the "vapor barrier", by which I'm guessing you are imagining poly sheeting) are likely in the wrong place. Do not build a double vapor barrier around your studs. They will get wet, they will have no way to dry, and they will rot.
There is an excellent resource called Building Science Corporation that has a great deal of free information from people who have been in the building trade for a long time. Much of it is both enjoyable to read and written by a Canadian. Here is an article that summarizes many of the challenges of controlling frost and condensation inside walls and roofs.
You will also need to be aware of the potential for ice damming if you plan to use the building during the winter -- that is, if you plan to heat the interior while there is snow on the roof.
Here is a corrected design similar to what you want to build -- but note the lack of a vapor barrier on the inside of the wall. Note also that the Tyvek / housewrap goes outside of the plywood sheathing that attaches to the studs. I suppose you could add a second layer of protective plywood instead of the cladding, but this also gives you an opportunity to go hog-wild with decorative cladding to your taste... its main job is to keep weather off the housewrap.


I've built many sheds and cabins using T1-11. The main reason to use T1-11 is that is functions as both the sheathing AND siding. Some of the other answers don't seem to be aware of this. Not to be pedantic, but T1-11 is not the same as "plywood siding", as the title of your question suggests. T1-11 comes both as plywood and OSB, and it is not just siding. When primed and painted, and given proper maintenance, T1-11 is just as structurally sound as other combinations of sheathing and siding, and will last for a good 30 years or more.
The main advantage of using separate layers for sheathing (e.g. 1/2" plywood) and siding (e.g. cedar shingles, vinyl crap) is that this allows you to replace the part that is exposed to the weather without touching the sheathing. It also allows you to put an impermeable layer between the sheathing and siding, eg tar paper, house wrap, etc. But if the intended use of the cabin is 30 years, there's no real advantage in separating the layers.
If this is for a 3-season cabin, go ahead and use T1-11. Yes, it might not last 100 years and might/might not be up to code, but it definitely works. This morning I went by a cabin I built 15 years ago with T1-11  and it looks just as it was when new.

At one time, homes were built exactly as you describe in your layer list (though house wrap had yet to be invented). It's a viable approach, though it's been improved upon over the decades for various reasons. Here are a few.

Omitting wall sheathing under the siding means your house wrap is essentially against the insulation. This makes it more difficult to seal seams, etc.

Not having sheathing means fasteners through the siding that don't hit framing tend to push the house wrap and insulation around, possible displacing or compacting it.

Not sandwiching the house wrap between rigid layers leaves room for more air movement (and the possibility of leaks).

As the siding degrades over time you lose some diagonal stability in your walls which would otherwise be maintained by a proper sheathing layer.


You'll want to take extra care to seal the envelope well before applying the siding, and you'll want to be sure the siding fits tightly to all framing to eliminate air leaks and rodent ingress. You'll want to caulk all seams and flash and caulk joints around windows and doors well.
There's some absurd fear-mongering happening on this page by folks with no experience in such ventures. Ignore it; the building is not going to collapse. For your purposes, this may work just fine. Accept the drawbacks and carry on.

Thank you. I like this part: "There's some absurd fear-mongering happening on this page by folks with no experience in such ventures. Ignore it; the building is not going to collapse. For your purposes, this may work just fine. Accept the drawbacks and carry on."

Do not proceed. This is a question for an architect.
What you show in this picture does not meet even the minimal requirements for a habitable space. It is just a shed. It's just sheathing and framing, not much better than a tent. If you were building a shed to store things in Ontario atop a forested hill, I would say send it - but with the caveat that losing a lawnmower or a motorcycle isn't the end of the world.
If you die, it is the end of your world. Landslides, windstorms, frost heave, forest fire are very real risks. People die from living in underspec'ed buildings. Architects know the code, the climate, the fault lines, and plan everything to spec down to the fasteners and locations, the window thickness, and most importantly the foundation.
Homesteading off the grid is terribly romantic, but social media has been largely ignorant to the real challenges of doing it.

I edited the question to clarify that the cabin is just for occasional use, not homesteading.

@User1974: Doesn't really matter.  If you plan to have humans sleep there, the safety concerns apply.

and from a safety perspective, it's worse than a tent.  Much heavier (so collapse can cause real injury), much more flammable, much harder to escape in an emergency.

Holy Chicken Little, batman. This is also not an answer.
